# Applescript to make indesign changes to group of text boxes

Tags: applescript, adobe, adobe-indesign

I currently have an AppleScript that makes small changes to text boxes in an indesign document. The script goes page by page, and if an applied object style is called a certain name and it contains a certain character, it will apply a paragraph style. Here's an example of my script:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign"
    repeat with x from 1 to count pages
        set ThisPage to page x
        tell ThisPage
            if exists (text frames whose (name of applied object style is "PriceBox" and contents contains "/$")) then
                set myFrames to (text frames whose (name of applied object style is "PriceBox" and contents contains "/$"))
                tell myFrames
                    repeat with r from 1 to count items
                        set applied paragraph style of paragraphs of item r of myFrames to "2forPrice"
                    end repeat
                end tell
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

What this does is it goes to the first page of a document, and if there is a text box that is called "PriceBox" and the text box has the characters "/$" in it, it will change the paragraph style to a named style "2forPrice".

This works great when there is 1 "listing" on each page. I am trying to make this work where there are multiple groups of listings and make the script go to each and every group of boxes separately and run the script. Any way to tell if this can be done by group, rather than by page?

Thank you for your help!!

UPDATE:
Here are the screenshots of what it does, I skipped a few steps to make it work, but I rather use groups of boxes. 
[image: This is what's considered a "group", I want to put all these boxes in one group.]

[image: Here is how all the groups are laid out on one page]

[image: Take a look at the changes to the prices if it's a "2for", for example 2/$6]

Picture1: This is what's considered a "group", I want to put all these boxes in one group.

Picture2: Here is how all the groups are laid out on one page

Picture3: Take a look at the changes to the prices if it's a "2for", for example 2/$6

I want my script to go group by group, instead of page by page, to do the if statement and change the paragraph style. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

@Ted: Depending on how well an app’s Apple Event Object Model is implemented, you should be able to do all that in a single command:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign"
  tell front document
    tell pages
      tell (text frames whose name of applied object style is "PriceBox" and contents contains "/$")
        set applied paragraph style of paragraphs to "2forPrice"
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

(Tip: Apple event IPC is RPC + *queries*, not OOP.)

[ETA] As commenter below notes, this won’t work on grouped text frames, so here’s a recursive variation that will:

```
to walkGroups(groupRef)
  tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
    tell groupRef
      tell (text frames whose name of applied object style is "PriceBox" and contents contains "/$")
        if it exists then
          set applied paragraph style of paragraphs to "2forPrice"
        end if
      end tell
      repeat with subgroupRef in groups
        my walkGroups(subgroupRef)
      end repeat
    end tell
  end tell
end walkGroups


tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
  my walkGroups(front document)
end tell
```

Comment: In principle, sure. In practice, thought — at least in my experience — this kind of 'dense' coding tends to cause headaches. The apple events system is *old* tech. Queries are not as robust as one might hope, and debugging any errors would force us to expand your implicit iterations into the explicit ones I've written. I mean, more power to you if it works; there's a definite 'cool' factor to your code.  But the 'cool' factor comes at a price.

Comment: It’s not “dense”. It either works or it doesn’t. That’s up to the app. If a single query + command doesn’t work, then rewrite your script to use loops to send simpler queries over multiple commands, understanding that code will be more complicated, bug-prone, and slow. AppleScript has a nasty habit of inculcating users to work on assumptions and, while to some extent unavoidable (due to ubiquitously poor documentation), down that road [cargo cult programming](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/cargo-cult-programming.html) also lies.

Comment: Nothing beats theory like practise, natch. My CC license only covers Illustrator, but I’ve managed to dig out InDesign CS6 to test the above on a mockup document. Seems to work fine, once I added the `tell document…` block (which we all forgot:). AI and ID AEOMs have plenty of quirks, but on balance they’re still some of the most thorough and robust implementations in the “AppleScript” ecosystem. Amazing tech when it works.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm actually going to try to strip my code a little to make this code from @foo work. However, this still does not let me do what I have to do.This works best when there is a set of boxes on one page. For example, if I have 50 pages in a document, these are the steps it will take: 1. Look for the "PriceBox" and check if it has "/$" in that box (this makes it a "2forPrice" meaning 2/$5 as a sale price, rather than a single price ($299). Then it will go to the next page and start the loop again. I'm trying to have the script do the same thing with multiple sets of boxes.

Comment: @MikeVolpe — again, it would be nice to have a sample document to test.

Comment: I've added an answer that shows how to do it with a single query. The trick? Use stories to the text frames.

Comment: @user1754036: Operating on stories might not work as intended if a story flows over more than one text frame. (I’m guessing the way Mike’s document is built, price texts are set independently in their own text frames, not flowed in as part of a longer story, in which case either route should do.)

Comment: @Mike: 1. Like Ted, I’m not really following. While SO lacks a convenient way to share working test files, perhaps amending your question with before+after screenshots can clarify your requirements?  2. Upon reflection, a better solution might be to use ID’s regular expression matching rules to apply styles automatically to specific patterns of characters. That has the advantage of being dynamic behavior, so refreshes automatically as the document is edited.

Comment: Hello, I've attached screenshots of exactly what the script is doing to the price boxes. Thank you again for the help!!

Comment: the solution proposed here won't find grouped text frames

Comment: @user: Eh, that’s annoying. (Clearly my ID-fu is rusty. Illustrator doesn’t have this limitation: `every page item of document` refers to *all* objects regardless of layers or grouping.) Your suggestion of using `stories of document` may work best, caveat the need to filter by text frame formatting (which may not work as intended if stories flow over multiple text frames). If not, I’ve revised my original answer to traverse nested groups as well.

Comment: And yeah, using GREP in Paragraph Styles might also be an option. Seeing OP’s screenshot, I suspect GREP is already being used to format dollars vs cents, so piling more patterns on top might get a bit too much for ID to handle. I’ll leave OP and others to try it for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

ONE-LINER / STORY approach

As you can see, searching for text frames by scouring pages, spreads, paste boards, groups, etc. can be difficult. The script API doesn't have a command for "give me all text frames in the layout regardless of where they are".

The workaround here is to use the story object. If you ask InDesign to give you a list of all stories (or text flows) in a layout, you'll get them regardless of where they may exist within the layout.

The example below starts with all stories that are associated with a text frame and then matches only the stories where the text frame's object style is "test". It then applies a paragraph style to the paragraphs of those stories.

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2018"
        set applied paragraph style of paragraphs of (stories of document 1 whose class of (object reference of item 1 of text containers) is text frame and name of applied object style of item 1 of text containers = "test" and contents contains "/$") to "Body Text"
end tell
```

IF NESTED TELLS ARE PREFERRED

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2018"
    tell document 1
        tell (stories whose class of (object reference of item 1 of text containers) is text frame and name of applied object style of item 1 of text containers = "test" and contents contains "/$")
            set applied paragraph style of paragraphs to "Body Text"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "page items" of the page. If there is a group, it will count as a page item. You will then have to programmatically inspect each group for text frames.

Eg, if there are 3 text frames and one group of 2 text frames, the text frame count for the page will be 3, but the page items count will be 4 (the three ungrouped text frames plus the one group of 2 text frames.

Comment: This is helpful but not a full answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know how to work InDesign — I have an old copy of it, but it would be nice if you provided an example document that I could download and test — but just in terms of AppleScript you probably want to do something like so:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign"
    repeat with this_page in pages
        tell this_page
            set text_frames_list to (text frames whose name of applied object style is "PriceBox" and contents contains "/$")
            repeat with a_text_frame in text_frames_list
                tell a_text_frame
                    set applied paragraph style of paragraphs of a_text_frame to "2forPrice"
                end tell
            end repeat
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: doesn't handle grouped text frames